# CASE in INNER join not returning desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, inner-join

For the following dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE ServiceOrder (
  ServiceOrderId INTEGER ,
  EventStatus VARCHAR(100),
  Date DATE
);

INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0001, 'status1A', CONVERT(date,'01.01.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0001, 'status1B', CONVERT(date,'12.01.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0001, 'status2', CONVERT(date,'01.02.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0001, 'status2', CONVERT(date,'22.02.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0001, 'status3', CONVERT(date,'01.03.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0001, 'status4', CONVERT(date,'01.04.2022',104));

INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0002, 'status1A', CONVERT(date,'12.01.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0002, 'status1B', CONVERT(date,'01.01.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0002, 'status2', CONVERT(date,'01.02.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0002, 'status2', CONVERT(date,'22.02.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0002, 'status3', CONVERT(date,'01.03.2022',104));
INSERT INTO ServiceOrder VALUES (0002, 'status4', CONVERT(date,'12.01.2022',104));
```

I need the smallest date for each status by ServiceOrderId. (in the following result, you can see status2 only show once by ServiceOrderId) Like this:

```
SELECT ServiceOrderId, EventStatus, MIN(Date) 
FROM ServiceOrder
GROUP BY ServiceOrderId, EventStatus ;

tableA, RESULT:
    ServiceOrderId  EventStatus MIN(Date)
    1   status1A    2022-01-01
    1   status1B    2022-01-12 
    1   status2     2022-02-01
    1   status3     2022-03-01
    1   status4     2022-04-01
    2   status1A    2022-01-12 
    2   status1B    2022-01-01
    2   status2     2022-02-01
    2   status3     2022-03-01
    2   status4     2022-04-01
```

and, if the ServiceOrderId contain both EventStatus status1A    and status1B I need the one with the smallest date.

The following works in MySQL:

```
SELECT tableC.ServiceOrderId, tableC.EventStatus, MIN(tableC.Date) as tableCDate
FROM ServiceOrder as tableC, 
    (SELECT ServiceOrderId, MAX(tableADate) as tableBDate
    FROM (SELECT ServiceOrderId, EventStatus, MIN(Date) as tableADate
        FROM ServiceOrder
        GROUP BY ServiceOrderId, EventStatus
        ) as tableA
    WHERE EventStatus IN ('status1A', 'status1B')
    GROUP BY ServiceOrderId
    ) as tableB
where (CASE WHEN EventStatus IN ('status1A', 'status1B')
        THEN tableC.ServiceOrderId <> tableB.ServiceOrderId 
             and tableC.Date <> tableB.tableBDate 
        ELSE TRUE END
        )
GROUP BY tableC.ServiceOrderId, tableC.EventStatus
```

Wanted result:

```
ServiceOrderId  EventStatus tableCDate
1   status1A 2022-01-01
1   status2 2022-02-01
1   status3 2022-03-01
1   status4 2022-04-01
2   status1B 2022-01-01
2   status2 2022-02-01
2   status3 2022-03-01
2   status4 2022-01-12
```

but I need it in SQL Server and it won't work. There is a problem with the case. I try to change it like the following, but it won't filter out between status1A and status1B.

```
SELECT tableC.ServiceOrderId, tableC.EventStatus, MIN(tableC.Date) as tableCDate
FROM ServiceOrder as tableC
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ServiceOrderId, MAX(tableADate) as tableBDate
    FROM (SELECT ServiceOrderId, EventStatus, MIN(Date) as tableADate
          FROM ServiceOrder
          GROUP BY ServiceOrderId, EventStatus) as tableA
    WHERE EventStatus IN ('status1A', 'status1B')
    GROUP BY ServiceOrderId
    ) as tableB
ON (CASE WHEN EventStatus IN ('status1A', 'status1B')
        AND tableC.ServiceOrderId <> tableB.ServiceOrderId 
        AND tableC.Date <> tableB.tableBDate 
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END
    )=1
GROUP BY tableC.ServiceOrderId, tableC.EventStatus
```

Result (not wanted):

```
ServiceOrderId  EventStatus tableCDate
1   status1A    2022-01-01
1   status1B    2022-01-12
1   status2 2022-02-01
1   status3 2022-03-01
1   status4 2022-04-01
2   status1A    2022-01-12
2   status1B    2022-01-01
2   status2 2022-02-01
2   status3 2022-03-01
2   status4 2022-01-12
```

Comment: the mysql query uses a cross join and not like the second a inner join

Comment: @nbk, well, then the question is how to make the cross join in MSSQL?
I tested the mysql here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yx8hz93a
I tested teh mssql here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62fea/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is a bit hard to comprehend.
I will handle 1A1B and others separately and union them at the end.

```sql
SELECT SO.ServiceOrderId, SO.EventStatus, AB.MinDate
FROM
(
    SELECT ServiceOrderId, MIN(Date) AS MinDate
    FROM ServiceOrder
    WHERE EventStatus IN ('status1A', 'status1B')
    GROUP BY ServiceOrderId
) AB INNER JOIN ServiceOrder SO
    ON AB.ServiceOrderId = SO.ServiceOrderId AND AB.MinDate = SO.Date
WHERE SO.EventStatus IN ('status1A', 'status1B')
UNION
SELECT ServiceOrderId, EventStatus, MIN(Date) AS MinDate
FROM ServiceOrder
WHERE EventStatus NOT IN ('status1A', 'status1B')
GROUP BY ServiceOrderId, EventStatus
```